# Storing Token into object in js file from URL

Tags: angularjs

I am facing some issue while storing token from email link.Actually,i am using angularjs. For example i got this link to my mail http://65.147.100.19:8090/UAR-Machine-V0.3_2/#/build/?456456 in this link i want to store the token "?456456" when i clicked the link it i will  redirect to login page during this redirecting i want to store this token as an object.The token validates the authenticated user with that token.It's same like token validation but i want to do this validation with that dynamic token which is published in the URL.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: please add some code and more details on where you want to store the token, and what backend you are using?

Comment: your question is not clear. Kindly explain in better way.

Comment: Just console.log(window.location), see if you are getting something.

Comment: Actually we are using python at the back to trigger the link appending some token to the link at last to some defined mails.Now, we have to store that dynamic token when we clicked the link during run time or redirecting to any page.

Comment: Actually, we are doing automation work.Before what we have is when we did some modification in yaml file which is located in github it automatically triggered the new job in jenkins with the scripts of python engine  and build job will trigger after the completion of build the python will trigger deployment job.Here it is all automation now, we are planning to deploy the application with some approval.So,python will trigger the link to user's mail with dynamic token append to it.The mail has been sent after build completion just its for approving the deployment proceess with that token based.

Answer (score 0):

Here am called my url(with appen my details for sessionID and etc) like bellow,

```
"http://localhost:7070/dais-portal/#/SocialLandingPage/"+userID+"/"+entityId+"/"+channelID+"/"+sessionID
```

js file

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    /*
     * $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
     */
    $stateProvider

    .state('SocialLandingPage', {
        url: '/SocialLandingPage/:userID/:entityId/:channelID/:sessionID',
        views: {
            'content-page': {
                templateUrl: 'loginPage/view/dais-dummy-landing-page.html'
            }
        }
    })
    }
```

dummy-landing-page.html, here called one controller. And am getting all values.(like userID, entityId, channelID and sessionID)

from that controller.
Am getting like this,

```
$scope.userID = $stateParams.userID;
$scope.entityId = $stateParams.entityId;
$scope.channelID = $stateParams.channelID;
$scope.sessionID = $stateParams.sessionID;
```